# Volume by tripple integration between cylinder and hyperboloid

Tags: integration, volume, change-of-variable

Find the volume bounded by the cylinder X^2+ Y^2= 4 and hyperbolic X^2 + Y^2- z^2=1

Can someone suggest me how to take the limits.

- i tried following limits
- z from 1 to root(X^2+ Y^2-1)
- x from 0 to root(4-y^2)
- y from 0 to 2

Can someone tell me mistakes if any and also tell limits in cylindrical coordinates please.

Comment: note that $z=\sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)}$ so $(x^2+y^2)$ cannot reach to $4$

Comment: Thank u. I will try improving limits

Comment: It should be z=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)-1} as there i (-) sign in the ques.

Comment: yes, sorry: then $x^2+y^2$ shall start from $1$

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: Now are my limits correct?

Comment: make a geometric sketch, e.g. in the $x=0$ plane.

Comment: then it is clear that you have better and pass to cylindrical c.

Comment: Ok i will try. Thank u

Comment: Thank u so much.I founded the answer= 4 root(3)pie using cylindrical coordinates

Comment: good ! (so you might mark the hint as accepted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

[image: Int_Hyperb_1]

so you will have
$- \sqrt{r^2-1} \le z \le \sqrt{r^2-1}, \; 1 \le r \le 2$